# how to extract DER encoded certificate from base64 string

Tags: php, encoding, certificate

Looking for help on how to decode the following base64 MerkleTreeLeaf string.

The MerkleTreeLeaf structure is a composite data structure that contains a timestamp as well as a digital certificate.

The structure is encoded as a Base64 encoded byte string. Within this byte string, there is an actual certificate encoded in DER format.

I am looking for a php solution to extract the DER encoded certificate.

Here is a sample of the base64 encoded string

```
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
```

If i use the online [base64 convertors tool](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/base64_decode/) it shows some detail but obviously its unreadable. If I can extract the DER encoded certificate then I can use openssl to parse it.

Comment: If it helps, i believe there is a python solution here [python script](https://github.com/wgoulet/CTPyClient/blob/master/parse.py) which may give some clues but not sure  how i can do the same in php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can approach it the same way as the Python script in your comment, simply comparing the [Python unpack documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) with [the one for PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php). In case you only want the unparsed certificate, you can get away with

```
<?php

function mtl_to_x509($base64str) {
    $raw = base64_decode($base64str);
    // Parse the decoded string
    $cert_length = unpack('N', chr(0).substr($raw, 12, 3))[1];
    $cert_as_asn1 = substr($raw, 15, $cert_length);
    return $cert_as_asn1;
}

$example = "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";

print mtl_to_x509($example);

?>
```

To see that this does the job, note that we can indeed parse it with openssl:

```
$ php mtl_to_x509.php | openssl x509 -inform der -noout -text | grep Subject:
        Subject: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.1=Wilmington, C=US, ST=California, L=Mountain View/businessCategory=Private Organization/serialNumber=2158113, O=Symantec Corp, OU=for ct testing-- ecc, CN=evpro1.ev1.symantec.com
```

In case you end up needing the rest of the data structure as well, the relevant unpacking will look as follows:

```
$version = unpack('C', substr($raw, 0, 1))[1];
$ctype = unpack('C', substr($raw, 1, 1))[1];
$timestamp = unpack('J', substr($raw, 2, 8))[1];
$entry_type = unpack('n', substr($raw, 10, 2))[1];
```

Comment: this works! however, for the $version, ctype etc i get this messge "Warning: unpack(): 64-bit format codes are not available for 32-bit versions of PHP"

Comment: That's probably the `$timestamp` causing the issue, as parsing an unsigned long long won't work on 32-bit. To see what the value should be, you could use `print_r(unpack('C*', substr($raw, 2, 8)));`:

`Array(     [1] => 0     [2] => 0    [3] => 1    [4] => 77    [5] => 12    [6] => 52    [7] => 69    [8] => 113)`.

That is, the timestamp should be

`113*256^0 + 69*256^1 + 252*256^2 + 12*256^3 + 77*256^4 + 1\*256^5 = 1430441969009.`

Comment: Or just as two 32-bit integers: `print_r(unpack('N*', substr($raw, 2, 8)));` gives

`Array(    [1] => 333    [2] => 217859441)`.

and

`217859441 + 333*256^4 = 1430441969009.`

Comment: in your solution how did you come up with the numbers 12, 3 in `$cert_length` and 15 in `$cert_as_asn1` -- reason i ask is because I have another base64 string I am trying to parse but it doesn't quite work. You can find the base64 string here: https://jpst.it/JgX9

Comment: @user3436467: I just got them from the example provided in the comment to the original post, but you could also find them in the CT RFC; https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6962.txt

Comment: thanks for responding on this old resolved question. i looked over the python script and RFC and couldnt exactly see those number but if you have time would really like to see how you might apply this to another string. I opened a new threaad here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673634/trouble-unpacking-base64-string