# trouble unpacking base64 string

Tags: php

I have a base64 encoded merkle leaf string as described here https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6962.txt - I am trying to unpack/retrieve the certificate from leaf_input but not quite getting the data i need from it. Using a standard base64 decoder http://string-functions.com/base64decode.aspx I can see there is a binary encoded ssl certificate packed inside the string.

```
$raw = "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";
```

I tried using the steps in this thread [how to extract DER encoded certificate from base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686497/how-to-extract-der-encoded-certificate-from-base64-string/) to unpack and while i can see some of the binary output it appears to be incomplete.

When I write the binary output to a file and save with .der extension and run it i get an error saying

> "This file is invalid for use as the following: Security Certificate".

However, the base64 encoded string in the example on the other thread does work whereas with mine only partially.

Here is the script i am using to unpack.

```
<?php

function mtl_to_x509($base64str) {
    $raw = base64_decode($base64str);
    // Parse the decoded string
    $cert_length = unpack('N', chr(0).substr($raw, 12, 3))[1];
    $cert_as_asn1 = substr($raw, 0, $cert_length);
    print_r($cert_as_asn1);

    $file = 'C:/test.der';
    file_put_contents($file, $cert_as_asn1);
}

$raw = "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";

print mtl_to_x509($raw);

?>
```

In the response I do see binary encoded data but i dont believe its complete because when i run the file i get the above mentioned error.

I am not sure if these two lines are correct but not sure how i can determine that.

```
$cert_length = unpack('N', chr(0).substr($raw, 12, 3))[1];
$cert_as_asn1 = substr($raw, 0, $cert_length);
```

any ideas?

Comment: I got something like this after decode: [http://pastebin.com/eSFPnwSg](http://pastebin.com/eSFPnwSg)

Comment: Yes, this is just a broken preview of whats inside. I am i trying to extract the certificate in its entirety from the b64 string.

Comment: "I have a base64 string.."  - base64 is just a way to make ASCII from binary. It does not say anything about the inherent structure of the data which means it can be anything. To find out how to extract the certificate from it it might be helpful to know the inherent structure of this data or at least which program produced these data.

Comment: @steffen ullrich, its known as a merkle leaf structure as described here https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6962.txt - i would be looking at extracting the certificate from the leaf_input. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a base64 encoded merkle leaf string ...

It looks like you really have a signed certificate timestamp. There is no certificate inside this one, only the TBSCertificate:

```
3.2.  Structure of the Signed Certificate Timestamp

   enum { certificate_timestamp(0), tree_hash(1), (255) }
     SignatureType;

   enum { v1(0), (255) }
     Version;

     struct {
         opaque key_id[32];
     } LogID;

     opaque TBSCertificate<1..2^24-1>;

     struct {
       opaque issuer_key_hash[32];
       TBSCertificate tbs_certificate;
     } PreCert;

     opaque CtExtensions<0..2^16-1>;
```

To get to the real certificate you would need also the signature of the issuer which you don't have:

```
Certificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    tbsCertificate       TBSCertificate,
    signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
    signatureValue       BIT STRING  }
```

This TBSCertificate starts at offset 47 (1163 octets). The extracted data can be piped into `openssl asn1parse -inform der` where you can view this structure:

```
    0:d=0  hl=4 l=1159 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 cons: cont [ 0 ]        
    6:d=2  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :02
    9:d=1  hl=2 l=  16 prim: INTEGER           :64751A312C259E6E7302F1DBED1793C2
   27:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
   29:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha256WithRSAEncryption
   40:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
   42:d=1  hl=2 l= 119 cons: SEQUENCE          
   44:d=2  hl=2 l=  11 cons: SET               
   46:d=3  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE          
   48:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :countryName
   53:d=4  hl=2 l=   2 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :US
   57:d=2  hl=2 l=  29 cons: SET               
   59:d=3  hl=2 l=  27 cons: SEQUENCE          
   61:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :organizationName
   66:d=4  hl=2 l=  20 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :Symantec Corporation
   88:d=2  hl=2 l=  31 cons: SET               
   90:d=3  hl=2 l=  29 cons: SEQUENCE          
   92:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :organizationalUnitName
   97:d=4  hl=2 l=  22 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :Symantec Trust Network
  121:d=2  hl=2 l=  40 cons: SET               
  123:d=3  hl=2 l=  38 cons: SEQUENCE          
  125:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
  130:d=4  hl=2 l=  31 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3
  163:d=1  hl=2 l=  30 cons: SEQUENCE          
  165:d=2  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTCTIME           :150921000000Z
  180:d=2  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTCTIME           :161022235959Z
  195:d=1  hl=4 l= 295 cons: SEQUENCE          
  199:d=2  hl=2 l=  19 cons: SET               
  201:d=3  hl=2 l=  17 cons: SEQUENCE          
  203:d=4  hl=2 l=  11 prim: OBJECT            :jurisdictionCountryName
  216:d=4  hl=2 l=   2 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :NZ
  220:d=2  hl=2 l=  29 cons: SET               
  222:d=3  hl=2 l=  27 cons: SEQUENCE          
  224:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :businessCategory
  229:d=4  hl=2 l=  20 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :Private Organization
  251:d=2  hl=2 l=  14 cons: SET               
  253:d=3  hl=2 l=  12 cons: SEQUENCE          
  255:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :serialNumber
  260:d=4  hl=2 l=   5 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :35976
  267:d=2  hl=2 l=  11 cons: SET               
  269:d=3  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE          
  271:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :countryName
  276:d=4  hl=2 l=   2 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :NZ
  280:d=2  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SET               
  282:d=3  hl=2 l=  11 cons: SEQUENCE          
  284:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :postalCode
  289:d=4  hl=2 l=   4 prim: UTF8STRING        :1010
  295:d=2  hl=2 l=  20 cons: SET               
  297:d=3  hl=2 l=  18 cons: SEQUENCE          
  299:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :stateOrProvinceName
  304:d=4  hl=2 l=  11 prim: UTF8STRING        :New Zealand
  317:d=2  hl=2 l=  17 cons: SET               
  319:d=3  hl=2 l=  15 cons: SEQUENCE          
  321:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :localityName
  326:d=4  hl=2 l=   8 prim: UTF8STRING        :Auckland
  336:d=2  hl=2 l=  54 cons: SET               
  338:d=3  hl=2 l=  52 cons: SEQUENCE          
  340:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :streetAddress
  345:d=4  hl=2 l=  45 prim: UTF8STRING        :Ground Floor, Anz Centre, 23-29 Albert Street
  392:d=2  hl=2 l=  37 cons: SET               
  394:d=3  hl=2 l=  35 cons: SEQUENCE          
  396:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :organizationName
  401:d=4  hl=2 l=  28 prim: UTF8STRING        :ANZ Bank New Zealand Limited
  431:d=2  hl=2 l=  25 cons: SET               
  433:d=3  hl=2 l=  23 cons: SEQUENCE          
  435:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :organizationalUnitName
  440:d=4  hl=2 l=  16 prim: UTF8STRING        :Web Technologies
  458:d=2  hl=2 l=  34 cons: SET               
  460:d=3  hl=2 l=  32 cons: SEQUENCE          
  462:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
  467:d=4  hl=2 l=  25 prim: UTF8STRING        :cdn.Pre-prod-sdpanz.co.nz
  494:d=1  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE          
  498:d=2  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
  500:d=3  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
  511:d=3  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
  513:d=2  hl=4 l= 271 prim: BIT STRING        
  788:d=1  hl=4 l= 371 cons: cont [ 3 ]        
  792:d=2  hl=4 l= 367 cons: SEQUENCE          
  796:d=3  hl=2 l=  36 cons: SEQUENCE          
  798:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Subject Alternative Name
  803:d=4  hl=2 l=  29 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:301B821963646E2E7072652D70726F642D736470616E7A2E636F2E6E7A
  834:d=3  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE          
  836:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Basic Constraints
  841:d=4  hl=2 l=   2 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:3000
  845:d=3  hl=2 l=  14 cons: SEQUENCE          
  847:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Key Usage
  852:d=4  hl=2 l=   1 prim: BOOLEAN           :255
  855:d=4  hl=2 l=   4 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:030205A0
  861:d=3  hl=2 l=  29 cons: SEQUENCE          
  863:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Extended Key Usage
  868:d=4  hl=2 l=  22 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:301406082B0601050507030106082B06010505070302
  892:d=3  hl=2 l= 102 cons: SEQUENCE          
  894:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Certificate Policies
  899:d=4  hl=2 l=  95 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:305D305B060B6086480186F84501071706304C302306082B06010505070201161768747470733A2F2F642E73796D63622E636F6D2F637073302506082B0601050507020230191A1768747470733A2F2F642E73796D63622E636F6D2F727061
  996:d=3  hl=2 l=  31 cons: SEQUENCE          
  998:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Authority Key Identifier
 1003:d=4  hl=2 l=  24 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:301680140159ABE7DD3A0B59A66463D6CF200757D591E76A
 1029:d=3  hl=2 l=  43 cons: SEQUENCE          
 1031:d=4  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 CRL Distribution Points
 1036:d=4  hl=2 l=  36 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:30223020A01EA01C861A687474703A2F2F73722E73796D63622E636F6D2F73722E63726C
 1074:d=3  hl=2 l=  87 cons: SEQUENCE          
 1076:d=4  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :Authority Information Access
 1086:d=4  hl=2 l=  75 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:3049301F06082B060105050730018613687474703A2F2F73722E73796D63642E636F6D302606082B06010505073002861A687474703A2F2F73722E73796D63622E636F6D2F73722E637274
```

Comment: I got the same result with offset 47 `$cert_as_asn1 = substr($raw, 47, $cert_length);` - Can you take a look at this b64 string from extra_data https://justpaste.it/v1u8 - Per RFC the extra_data should have the whole certificate chain. I would assume I should be able to get the real certificate from here?

Comment: @user3436467: the one from the paste has a real certificate at offset 3,length 1589 and another one at offset 1598, length 1327 inside.

Comment: that works - thank you! You've been a great help already but knowing I can get this data now, how can i work out these offsets myself? If you could update your solution with the procedure I would be most greatful.

Comment: @user3436467: since it is unknown what your base64 data are really are in each case it is just guessing with the help of a small script. In production you should not do such hacks but know what kind of data you have and parse the structures like they are defined in the RFC.